# CMake не находит PythonLibs под Windows

Tags: python, cmake

Хочу встроить Python в одно своё приложение, которое собирается с помощью CMake. Делаю в CMakeLists.txt так:

```
find_package(PythonLibs REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
...
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

Под Linux никаких проблем нет, всё собирается сразу. Поставил Python (последняя актуальная версия на данный момент - 3.6) на Windows. При установке выбрал "Установить для всех пользователей" и "Добавить Python в переменную PATH". После установки интерпретатор Python отлично работает. Однако CMake не может найти Python:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:138 (message):
  Could NOT find PythonLibs (missing: PYTHON_LIBRARIES PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindPythonLibs.cmake:255 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package)
```

В чём может быть проблема? И как заставить проект собираться на обоих ОС без проблем?

Answer (score 1):

Функция `find_package()` не ищет по всему вашему жесткому диску, а только в определенных директориях. На Линуксе, грубо говоря, все библиотеки лежат в одном месте, поэтому CMake без труда их находит.

На винде питон можно установить в какую угодно директорию, поэтому CMake необходимо вручную ткнуть мордой в нужную папку. О чем, собственно, он и сказал:

> Could NOT find PythonLibs (missing: PYTHON_LIBRARIES PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS)

Можете установить эти переменные в нужные значения, а можете установить переменную `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` и указать в ней папку с питоном. Должно сработать, по идее.

Comment: Судя по исходникам, разве оно не должно читать ключи из реестра?